# Clear form in custom submit action

Tags: sitecore-forms

Using Sitecore Forms, I have a custom submit action on a form that is redirecting to a media file; however, when the user hits back in the browser, they return to the form with the fields populated with their input. How do I clear the fields of the form so that they return to an empty form?

Comment: That's the default behavior of forms. The only way you can achieve your desired functionality is by emptying the form's fields when the page is reloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no OOTB functionality in Sitecore.

You need to use JavaScript to achieve this.

Take a look on this older question and try to implement answer:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38177982/wffm-how-to-clear-or-init-form-fields-when-press-back-button-on-browser